# Downloaded newer image for graphiteapp/graphite-statsd:latest

Tags: docker, apache-flink, graphite, flink-streaming, statsd

I want to install graphite on docker using steps given [here](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#docker)

```
  docker run -d\
 --name graphite\
 --restart=always\
 -p 80:80\
 -p 2003-2004:2003-2004\
 -p 2023-2024:2023-2024\
 -p 8125:8125/udp\
 -p 8126:8126\
 graphiteapp/graphite-statsd
```

which  gave me following warning at  first

```
Unable to find image 'graphiteapp/graphite-statsd:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from graphiteapp/graphite-statsd
```

Gave me the following error after all the pulls were done

```
Digest: sha256:3136b19fcdb9162c642cc1d2821172948346651a46b41ab63cc05c2962ea85c9
Status: Downloaded newer image for graphiteapp/graphite-statsd:latest
7af4b99efeb4bb7d0bc1ba1d8b4556d812adc87bc720c035998eeb54116e57f4
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint graphite (de38efe3b7ee88976d044ffe9948839c8058b06408f46f9857e4e689d9883ce9): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE).
```

Comment: Are u running behind a proxy? What OS are you using?

Comment: M not behind proxy and using MacOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning message just reports you that there is no such image locally and it starts to download it.

You get an error, because you have some service works on 80 port on your host. The `graphite` container cannot start, because it also needs 80 port to be used. So, you can stop service which uses port 80 or start `graphite` with another port, for example 81 and access it on port 81:

```
docker run -d\
--name graphite\
--restart=always\
-p 81:80\
-p 2003-2004:2003-2004\
-p 2023-2024:2023-2024\
-p 8125:8125/udp\
-p 8126:8126\
graphiteapp/graphite-statsd
```